# What data structure should i use in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a small project in MEAN stack but I can not figure out what data structure to use.

So, in this case, I don't have any reference in the store I just fetch store when a person asks for his or her stores.

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  stores: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Store' }]
});

var storeSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  title    : String
});
```

AND:

In this case, I give the store a reference of the person so when a person asks for his or her stores I fetch all the store which has a reference to the person.

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String
});

var storeSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  owner    : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String
});
```

Which one is better approach?

Answer (score 0):

First one is better to use as it helps in clean code and queries.